# How to transform lambda expressions to Sql queries on the fly?

Tags: c#, sql, lambda

I have a Expression Type variable. It has an expression to filter data.
For example, The expression lets SQL get data where LOCATION is 'KOR'.

- `{it => (it.LOCATION == "KOR")}`

This expression will be the WHERE clause in a SQL statement.
Converting lambda expression to Sql queries looks complicated because there are many different expressions.

How can I achieve this purpose without starting from scratch?
Are there any nice libraries?

***Added....***

I can get a string of a lambda expression by invoking the ToString() method.

- `"it => (((it.LOCATION == \"KOR\") OrElse (it.LOCATION == \"FRA\")) AndAlso (it.Value > 30000))"`

Comment: What's the expected output in terms of SQL query?

Comment: The expected output is WHERE LOCATION IN ('KOR', 'FRA') AND Value > 30000.

Comment: If you're looking for a generic solution you may consider the complexity of building a sql clause tree leading back to nested predicates theory. NHibernate or Entity Framework can help you in a different way.

Comment: Instead of supporting all expressions I'm going to limit vocabularies so implementing it'll be not too difficult. Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: It's all about nested clause. Translate a WHERE it's not difficult, but how will you deal with SELECT..FROM (SELECT..FROM..WHERE) INNER JOIN (SELECT..FROM) WHERE...AND...OR? The predicates have different priorities and different solving orders. Let us know :)

Comment: In my case the expression never has those keywords (SELECT, FROM, ...) and the input always goes to a WHERE clause. However, it requires some picky works as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979017/how-to-convert-lambda-expression-to-sql

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking for, but have you tried using Linq to Sql [Dynamic Linq](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/231706/Dynamic-query-with-Linq)